# Can you specify the datatyp of the arguments given to a Function (PHP5)

Tags: php, function, arguments

I want to specify the Datatype that can be given to a Function.

In this demo Code (as an example) I would like to Specify the Datatype of the Arguments given to the `"__construct()"` Function so that it only takes `INT`for the `$id`, and `Objects` of the Type `"example2"` for`$some_object`.

Do you have any idea how I can Achieve this?

```
<?php

    class example1{

        private $id;
        private $example2;
        function __construct($id,$some_object){
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->object = $some_object;
        }

        function do_something(){
            $this->example2->moep(); 
        }

    }
    class example2{
        public function moep(){
            print("MOEP!!!");
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have type hinting: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

But, to quote from the manual:

> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string.
>   Traits are not allowed either.

Comment: scalar typehints will likely be included in php 5.5. there was a discussion to include them in 5.4 already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

There's some type hinting in PHP5, but it doesn't allow for scalar types. So no for `int` and `string`, but yes for pretty much everything else (including `array`, strangely enough).

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Thank you very much!

I will have a close look at hinting.

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can only type hint object (and arrays). You can't type hint scalars:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 0):

check type in constructor and throw an exception if needed:

```
function __construct($id,$some_object){
    if (!is_int($id)) throw new UnexpectedValueException("Argument 1 must be an integer");
    if (!is_object($some_object)) throw new UnexpectedValueException("Argument 2 must be an instance of any object");

    $this->id = $id;
    $this->object = $some_object;
}
```

Comment: This is also very Helpfull..
 Thank you very much :)